# google is not defined in mvc4

Tags: google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to render **google geochart** inside partial view in mvc4 but it's showing **reference error:
"google is not defined"**

but in simple view it's rendering fine.below is step to render my geochat.i don't know what i am doing wrong or should fellow other step to render google geochat.

my partial view(**_mymap.cshtml**)

```
     <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
        <div id='visualization'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

                    function initialize() {
                        google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['geochart'] });
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
                    }

         function drawVisualization() {
                        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                        data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
                        data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' }); var ivalue = new Array();

                        data.addRows([[{ v: '002', f: 'Africa' }, 0, 'Click to Choose']]);
                        ivalue['002'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa';

                        data.addRows([[{ v: '150', f: 'Europe' }, 1, 'Click to Choose']]);
                        ivalue['150'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe';

                        data.addRows([[{ v: '019', f: 'Americas' }, 2, 'Click to Choose']]);
                        ivalue['019'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americas';

                        data.addRows([[{ v: '142', f: 'Asia' }, 3, 'Click to Choose']]);
                        ivalue['142'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia';

                        data.addRows([[{ v: '009', f: 'Australia' }, 4, 'Click to Choose']]);
                        ivalue['009'] = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceania';

                        var options = {
                            backgroundColor: { fill: '#FFFFFF', stroke: '#FFFFFF', strokeWidth: 0 },
                            colorAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 4, colors: ['#A8A8A8', '#939473', '#B1B38B', '#90AD89', '#87AAAD', ] },
                            legend: 'none',
                            backgroundColor: { fill: '#FFFFFF', stroke: '#FFFFFF', strokeWidth: 0 },
                            datalessRegionColor: '#f5f5f5',
                            displayMode: 'regions',
                            enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
                            resolution: 'continents',
                            sizeAxis: { minValue: 1, maxValue: 1, minSize: 10, maxSize: 10 },
                            region: 'world',
                            keepAspectRatio: true,
                            width: 600,
                            height: 400,
                            tooltip: { textStyle: { color: '#444444' }, trigger: 'focus' }
                        };
                        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

                        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
                            var selection = chart.getSelection();
                            //append_to_list(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0));
                        });


                        chart.draw(data, options);
}
    $(document).ready(function () {initialize();});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`drawVisualization` function is missing closing brace inside `script` tag. You have closed it after the end script tag in your code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {initialize();});
</script>

                } //this brace need to be inside script tag
```

Comment: thanks for reply. by mistake i have copied wrongly here.brace is inside the script tag.problem is google is not rendering in partial view.pls suggest how to resolve this issue

Comment: include the script in main view and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The loader uses `document.write` to inject JS and CSS, this can't be done after the document has finished loading(what is the case here, because you call `initialize` on `domready`)

define the callback in the call of `google.load` and not via `setOnLoadCallback`

```
function initialize() {
  google.load('visualization',
              '1', 
              { 'packages': ['geochart'] , callback: drawVisualization});
}
```